# New ECL Command related to RCPTT testing tool

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I am referencing this site "https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/ecl/new-command-guide/" for new ECL command creation.

As per that new command guide, I downloaded the `RCPTT plugin` sources into my eclipse workspace, and when I try to create new eclipse instance using these following plugins as per the guide, errors exists for eg., for `org.eclipse.rcptt.ecl.parser plugin`, unsatisfied version constraint `'org.antlr.runtime:[3.2.0, 3.3.0)'`.
**Why I am getting that, and which version of `org.antlr.runtime` I should have?**

Comment: It wants a version of at least 3.2.0 but less that 3.3.0. The easiest thing to do is download the whole IDE from http://eclipse.org/rcptt/download/

Answer (score 0):

You should install antlr runtime 3.2 version from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/